# XStream Tag not mapped

Tags: java, xml, xstream

i have an XML file , the mapping to java object is ok, but this tag 
`<Ressources>test</Ressources>` is not mapped it shows null in java , if i rename this tag with any other name the mapping works , but 'Ressources' is never mapped i don't know what's wrong with it !

any idea ?

i see that if capitalized  `<RESSOURCES>test</RESSOURCES>` it works !! , if i declare it capitalized in both xsd and xml it mapps well , but what's the difference ? i want this tag to be lowercase :s

Comment: have you mis-spelled resources?

Comment: not mis-spelled, its declared like this in the XSD , now i see that if capitalized it works !! , if a declare it capitalized in both xsd and xml it mapps well , but what's the difference ? i want this tag to be lowercase :s